# JDialog not closing on first click on X

Tags: java, swing

Here java code of that open JDialog:

```
public class AccountsInternalFrame extends JInternalFrame implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == applyFilterButton) {
        } else if (e.getSource() == cleanFilterButton) {
        } else if (e.getSource() == paymentAccountButton) {
        EditPaymentAccountDialog editPaymentAccountDialog = new EditPaymentAccountDialog(owner);
        editPaymentAccountDialog.setVisible(true);
        } 
    }
}
```

Here my dialog code:

```
    public class EditPaymentAccountDialog extends JDialog implements ActionListener {
        public EditPaymentAccountDialog(Frame owner) {
            super(owner, true);
            initialize();
        }



private void initialize() {
               buildGUI();
               initLogic();

               setPreferredSize(new Dimension(680, 280));
                pack();
                setLocationRelativeTo(null); // center
                setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        }

    private void buildGUI() {
        setTitle(SystemOptions.translate("edit.payment.account"));
        Component mainPanel = createMainPanel();
        add(mainPanel);
    }
}
```

So as result my dilog success show.
But when I click on X (upper right side) the dialog success hide, but again show. And after I again click X then dialog hide forever.

Why I need twice click on X to hide dialog?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow!

Answer (score 1):

Your dialog is a modal dialog. So its `setVisible(true)` method blocks until you close it. And you specify what should happen on close **after** the call to `setVisible(true)`:

```
setVisible(true);
setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
```

This also prevents your `initLogic()` code to be executed, by the way.

Don't make the dialog visible from the constructor. Let the use of your dialog choose when to make it visible. Constructing a dialog should construct it. Not make it visible, and block the calling code.

Comment: Post a **complete** minimal example reproducing the problem. By **complete**, I mean that I must be able to copy and paste your code, compile it, run it, and see the problem happening.